# VBA method 'delete' for worksheets failing since upgrade to Office Pro Plus

Tags: excel, vba

I have designed some macros in an Excel file to automatically copy some information from files in a dedicated folder to my xlsm file.

After the update to Office Pro Plus I noted it takes way longer to do the data import with the macro (15-20 mins now vs 2-5mins in the past). Furthermore, some part of the code just doesn't work anymore while it was not changed and always worked perfectly in the past!

For example I had one Sub created to delete all the tabs in my Excel file apart from the first one ("Menu").

```
Sub Reset()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Menu" Then ws.Delete
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Reset completed!"
End Sub
```

This code has always worked, but now I get an error that "Method Delete of object '_Worksheet' failed ". So the 'ws.Delete' statement is not valid anymore suddenly.

I tried working around this issue, but I couldn't code around it and I don't find on the internet why this Delete statement wouldn't work anymore?

Does somebody now how to fix this or where this comes from?
And why other macros take more time to run in Office Pro Plus?

Thank you and kind regards,
Anthony

Comment: Maybe figure out which worksheet it is (i.e. `Debug.Print ws.Name`) to try and isolate what is different about that sheet?

Comment: Did you double check the *do not delete* sheet name has not changed? It should be "Menu" as exact match. If you try to delete the last sheet on your book you will get this error

Comment: I would check to confirm that the sheet named "Menu" exists prior to executing this code.  If there's no "Menu" sheet, then you have an issue that needs to be resolved prior to doing the reset.  Also, add error handling for that Application.DisplayAlerts = False call.  If your code fails after it's called, then you leave Excel in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!

Just wanted to let you know that I was able to fix the issue by disabling the ACL add-on in Excel.

This add-on automatically creates a hidden tab ' Acerno_Cache_XXXX' in Excel. This tab had Visibility status '2- xlSheetVeryHidden' and therefore could not be deleted by the Macro. Changing the status of this sheet to Visible and disabling the ACL add-on allowed the procedure to run correctly now!